# How to get the id of element from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript

im trying to echo out a variable that is written from php using javascript. Well basically I have a drop down menu and what I am trying to do is echo out the number of stocks of the item selected by the user. Here is what I've got so far.

```
<select id="selectItem" onchange="stock(this)">
    <?php
     --- connection here ----
    $itemsStock = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemprofile");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $stock = $row['stock'];
            echo '<option value="'.$row['productname'].'" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['productname'].'</option>';
            $itemsStock[$id] = $stock;
        }

    ?>
</select>

Available stock: <div id="stockRemaining"></div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

var json_arr = <?php echo json_encode($itemsStock);?>;
var stockValues = JSON.parse(json_arr);

    function stock(sel)
    {
        var itemID = sel.value;
        console.log(itemID); // debug to see that you are getting the correct value
        document.getElementById('stockRemaining').innerHTML = stockValues[itemID];
    }

</script>
```

The convertion of array from php to jquery is fine, i tried echoing it out and it works fine, my problem is the stock() function, I think im doing something wrong on the action inside it cuz everytime I click a different item from the drop down menu, it doesnt show anything at all. Im pretty new to Jscript hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to the "realm" of JavaScript (JS). A quick note, [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) is not same as current JavaScript, it's a dialect made my Microsoft and was used it older IEs. It's now (thankfully) long gone. Your code is also not [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), jQuery it's just a JavaScript library, it's not a style of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using an `addEventListener`. I don't know whether your `onchange` event on your `select` element is firing or not..

I modified your `while` loop (which is in an Html Comment field in this snippet) just to add consistency is the declaration and usage..

---

### Code Snippet

with *(Sample Php Echo Data)*

```js
document.getElementById("selectItem").addEventListener("change", stock);

//var json_arr = <?php echo json_encode($itemsStock);?>;
//  you need to determine what kind of array this will actually be: i.e. sequential, non-sequential
//  reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#example-3898

//  I'm presuming it will be a non-sequential with this demo data.
var json_arr = '{ ' +
'\"001\" : \"12000\",' +
'\"002\" : \"7000\",' +
'\"003\" : \"200\",' +
'\"004\" : \"10\"' + 
'}';
  
var stockValues = JSON.parse(json_arr);

function stock(ev)
{
    var itemID = ev.target.selectedOptions.item().id;
    console.log("%o - %o", stockValues, ev.target.selectedOptions.item().id); // debug to see that you are getting the correct value
    document.getElementById('stockRemaining').innerHTML = stockValues[itemID];
}
```

```html
<select id="selectItem">
    <!--
    <?php
     --- connection here ----
    $itemsStock = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemprofile");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $stock = $row['stock'];
            $productname = $row['productname'];

            echo '<option value="'.$productname.'" id="'.$id.'">'.$productname.'</option>';

            $itemsStock[$id] = $stock;
        }

    ?>
    -->
    <option value="coke" id="001">coke</option>
    <option value="pepsi" id="002">pepsi</option>
    <option value="sprite" id="003">sprite</option>
    <option value="drpepper" id="004">drpepper</option>
</select>

Available stock: <div id="stockRemaining"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your select option to

```
<select id="selectItem" onchange="stock(this)">
```

now you can obtain the value in your stock function as

```
function stock(sel)
    {
        var itemID = sel.value;
        console.log(itemID); // debug to see that you are getting the correct value
        document.getElementById('stockRemaining').innerHTML = stockValues[itemID];
    }
```

You might want to create a javascript array from the PHP JSON

```
var json_arr = <?php echo json_encode($itemsStock);?>;
var stockValues = JSON.parse(json_arr);
```

Now the $itemstock is available as an array:

You can use:

```
document.getElementById('stockRemaining').innerHTML = stockValues[itemID];
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I got item "tinidor" on my drop down list, i tried picking it and i get this error on console log.
tinidor
testmode.php:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tinidor' of undefined

Comment: some obvious issues here: he's creating his array using `id` as the index, not `productname`.. which is what would be in the `sel.value` field.. also... you should consider doing `document.getElementById('selectItem').selectedOption.item().value` instead